# callbacks open/close database android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, callback

I have a class that takes care of database manipulation function and hides database details from the user (simple ORM scheme).

```
class Product {
     void create(){..}
     void update(){..}
     ... other CRUD Functions
}
```

the problem is that i have to call `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()` to get the database object in the beginning of each call of these functions, then close the database object at the end.

There are two problems here:

1. (performance issue) Opening and closing the database in each
   call.
2. (code re-factoring issue) repeating the same lines of code
   at the beginning and the end of each function!

Comment: Good question. I personally have always had the opendatabase and database close at the beginning / end of functions. This never caused that big performance problems, and I particularly did it because Android guards against you not closing the database object, which I do not know how will apply on class level variable.

Comment: You HAVE to open/close every time, or you WILL get errors. My app downloads 3 files in 3 threads all in all makes 80 inserts to database, and even though I opened and closed database every time I had to use **synchronized** in my methods or I got "database already opened" or "cannot close database" or "database not opened" since they were fighting for database.